# Front end react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, frontend

muchas gracias por leer y ayudarme !! Tengo que construir una screen (como la foto de debajo) que me muestre mis turnos o horarios que toma de una api, estos pueden ser de 60, 90 o 120 minutos. El desafio es como contruirlo (ya que no se como relacionar el view que contiene la info del turno con el text que dice, por ejemplo, 8:00), soy bastante nuevo así que no se como hacerlo! muestro imagenes para que se entienda. La complicacion es que dependiendo de la hora debería insertarse en el lugar exacto y no chocarse con otros turnos/reservas o lo que fuere.

No necesito la solución completa pero tal vez unas simples ideas me ayuden a construirlo.

Muchas Gracias!

[image: react native front end]

Comment: Claro, aqui tienes algunas ideas, por ejemplo podrías según la fecha y la hora generar un DIV que contenga el calendario, y basado en cada turno podrías crear un nuevo DIV ubicado al frente de la hora y el dia que le corresponde, con CSS puedes darle color y estilo a tu nueva creación! Ah y muy importante, comparar las hora de inicio y final de cada turno para que no se solapen o choquen. Espero que te hayan servidor mis ideas. Saludos. Y recuerda [ask]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!